# Get the next multiple of a string in python

Tags: python, integer

I have the length of a string. If this string is say 49, I want it to the find the next multiple of 16 which should be 64. I've researched and found the round function however, this lowers it down to 48 instead of 64.

So:
the number returned from the length of a string should be rounded to the NEXT multiple of 16 not the nearest.

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = number for checking
a = multiple to find

nearest_multiple = n + (a - n % a)
print(nearest_multiple)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can first divide by the number you want to be multiple of, ceil it and then multiply again:

```
import math
a = 59
N = 16
a_nex= math.ceil(a/N)*N
```

Answer (score 0):

The `math.ceil()` function might fix your issue. Not sure if that's gonna work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will solve yor problem:

```
    # String Length
    n = 49

    def nextMultiple(n,multiple):
        # Next Multiple of 16
        next_multiple = (multiple - (n % multiple)) + n
        print(next_multiple)

    nextMultiple(n,16)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).